# How can I permanently store an MP3 file using Python?

Tags: python, mp3

I am trying to write an alarm app, and want the user to set their own alarm sound. I have done about an hour of searching and have found nothing pertaining to MP3s. The closest I've seen is Pickle, which seems to only store things that are text based. I am using Atom if that changes anything.

Comment: Just open the file in binary mode and write the MP3 data to the file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.